# Display table for individual user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to view data of a specific user using the session. All the details come up when I 
login as an admin whose personid = 1. But when I try to log in as a separate user, the table is
not being displayed. I believe the fault is in the IFELSE part of the code. 
I have used joins to combine multiple tables. Is my syntax for the Where statement correct?

```
  protected function selectAll() {

   try {                                                   

        $this->pdo = $this->Connect();            

         session_start();
```

This section is used to see all shifts by an admin

```
       if( isset($_SESSION["personid"]) && $_SESSION["personid"] === '1' ) { 
       $sql = "select * from PersonShift "                 
             . " inner join Person on Person.PersonID = PersonShift.PersonID"                 
             . " inner join Role on Role.RoleID = PersonShift.RoleID"
             . " inner join BusShift on BusShift.ShiftNo = PersonShift.ShiftNo";               

       }
```

In this section, the logged in user can see only his particular shifts

```
        else if( isset($_SESSION["personid"]) && $_SESSION["personid"] !== '1' ) {

     $sql = "select * from PersonShift "                 
             . " inner join Person on Person.PersonID = PersonShift.PersonID"                 
             . " inner join Role on Role.RoleID = PersonShift.RoleID"
             . " inner join BusShift on BusShift.ShiftNo = PersonShift.ShiftNo"
             . "where PersonShift.PersonID = ".$_SESSION['personid'];  

        }                             

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);                        


        }                               

        $this->result = $stmt->fetchAll();                             

        $this->pdo = null;                        

        return $this->result;                                                

               } catch (\Exception $ex) {

               throw new \Exception($ex->getMessage());

       }                      

       }
```

Comment: You don't have a space between `... BusShift.ShiftNo = PersonShift.ShiftNo"` and `. "where PersonShift.PersonID ...` so it will be parsed as `BusShift.ShiftNo = PersonShift.ShiftNowhere PersonShift.PersonID`. Add a space -> `. " where PersonShift.PersonID ...`

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems there: first, the braces are not matching properly so the code is kind of unpredictable; second I don't see where you execute the query.

Please, try this:

```
protected function selectAll() 
{
    try {                                                   
        $this->pdo = $this->Connect();            
        session_start();

        if( isset($_SESSION["personid"]) && $_SESSION["personid"] === '1' ) 
        { 
          $sql = "select * from PersonShift "                 
             . " inner join Person on Person.PersonID = PersonShift.PersonID"                 
             . " inner join Role on Role.RoleID = PersonShift.RoleID"
             . " inner join BusShift on BusShift.ShiftNo = PersonShift.ShiftNo";               
        }
        else if( isset($_SESSION["personid"]) && $_SESSION["personid"] !== '1' ) 
        {
            $sql = "select * from PersonShift "                 
                   . " inner join Person on Person.PersonID = PersonShift.PersonID"                 
                   . " inner join Role on Role.RoleID = PersonShift.RoleID"
                   . " inner join BusShift on BusShift.ShiftNo = PersonShift.ShiftNo"
                   . "where PersonShift.PersonID = ".$_SESSION['personid'];  

        } // end if 

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute(); // Execute was missing

        //} This was misplaced

        $this->result = $stmt->fetchAll();                             

        $this->pdo = null;                        

        return $this->result;                                                

    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        throw new \Exception($ex->getMessage());
    }                      
} // end function
```

Comment: Sorted that out..still no results

Comment: Have you made sure that the session variables are correctly populated? and Have you tried those queries directly against the database to make sure they bring out the intended results?